# Laravel Spark Installation in MAC

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm new to mac and I don't know how to add path to the system. I have already cloned the file for spark and done composer update. I need to this next step. How do I do it in MAC?

Next, make sure the spark-installer directory is added to your systems $PATH variable, so that your machine will be able to locate the spark executable when you issue Spark commands.

Answer (score 12):

You do it by updating the `PATH` variable.

`export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

However, this will not persist. If you close the terminal window, the `PATH` will be restored to its original value. You need to add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`

Run this command to add the line to your `~/bash_profile`

`echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

To verify that you have the correct path: `echo $PATH`, and you should see `.composer/vendor/bin` in the middle of the output

For spark specifically, you need to add the path to the location where you cloned the repo.

`echo 'export PATH=path/to/spark/repo:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Here is a full list of commands to install Spark:

```
cd $HOME
git clone https://github.com/laravel/spark-installer.git
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/spark-installer:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
cd ~/spark-installer
composer install
spark
```